# Deciphering death certificate writing

Tags: palaeography, death-records, cause-of-death

I have another death certificate that I am struggling to read! This one is for my Great Great Grandmother who passed away in 1917.

I know that she died at Roundway Hospital in Devizes which was an asylum at the time.

## Occupation

[image: Occupation]

I can make out:

> of 17 Meadow Cottages, The ??? Salisbury

## Cause of Death:

[image: Cause of Death]

## Corrections

There is also an extra bit on the right of the certificate that seems to be corrections:

[image: Corrections]

The writing is small and I can only make out bits of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the first part is:

> Of 17 Meadow Cottages
>   The Friary (?)
>   Salisbury
>     and (? or 2nd ?)
>   Wife of ----
>   Scammell
>   a ----

I would guess from this that her husband's surname was Scammell but neither his forename nor his occupation were given. The informant, probably a hospital employee, may simply not have known.

The cause of death section is:

> (1) Chronic Bright's
>   Disease. Duration
>   not known
>   (2) Chronic Dilation
>   of stomach. Duration
>   not known
>   Suppurative Cholecystitis
>   (from gallstones)
>   Tuberculosis
>   of left Pleura PM Certified by
>   Sydney J Cole (?)

"PM" probably indicates that a postmortem was carried out. From the GRO's [guide](https://www.gro.gov.uk/gro/Content/Certificates/images/Death%20Cert%20PDF.pdf) (PDF) to death certificates, "Certified" means " the cause of death was given by the doctor in medical attendance of the deceased", i.e. Sydney Cole.

I think that the "primary" cause of death is (1), and (2) was causative or contributory to (1). The following non-numbered entries are other significant health issues that may have contributed to the death but were not immediate causes.

The final note is indeed a correction, and it appears itself to have been corrected, judging by the struck out text:

> Clerical error
>   in Col 6
>   Corrected on
>   the 8th February
>   1918
>   <s>on the authority 
>   of the Registrar
>
>   General</s>
>   By me
>   Arthur Mitchell
>   Registrar
>   in the presence
>   of
>   O Sheppard (?)
>   Sup<sup>t</sup> Registrar

Column 6 is the cause of death. If you look at the bottom of that section, "pleura" is written in above a crossed-out word that I can't read clearly. I think that is the correction of the clerical error that this refers to.